# local angular state blown away each time the redux store refreshes

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using angular 4 and I am using ngrx for global state management.

I have components that renders a number of child components:

`<div upload-list-item *ngFor="let upload of (uploads | async).items" [upload]="upload"></tbody>`

I want to store whether or not the item view is expanded or not in the local component's state.  If I was in react this where this value would live:

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: '[upload-list-item]',
  template: `
    <tr class="top-level" (click)="setExpanded()">
      <td>
        <a
          href="javascript:void(0)"
          title="Expand/Collapse Row"
          [class]="expanded ? 'datatable-icon-down' : 'datatable-icon-right'"
        >
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="expanded">
      <td class="detail-td" colspan="6">
        Expanded
      </td>
    </tr>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./upload-list-item.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class UploadListItemComponent {
  @Input() upload: Upload;

  expanded = false;

  setExpanded() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
}
```

The problem is, every time I the ngrx store is updated all the local state gets blown away or so it seems.

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: could you please share the code of your component, that loses local state?

Comment: @BorysKupar thank you, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't know by default which element has been changed, so it is re-rendering the whole list again, your components are destroyed and this is why you lose local state.

You could add `trackBy` function to ngFor, so Angular wouldn't re-render everything, but only modify changed component. Nice post [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5).

```
<div upload-list-item *ngFor="let upload of (uploads | async).items; trackBy: trackByFn"
 [upload]="upload"></tbody>
```

In you container component:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index; // or item.id
}
```

Alternatively, you can store local state for every upload-item in container component, the one that is rendering upload items.

Comment: is the sytax correct?  Is trackBy a directive, the parser throws an exception in angular 4

Comment: My bad, added trackBy in the wrong place. Please check the answer again. It should inside of *ngFor

Comment: my function is not getting called, it has the async pipe `<tbody upload-list-item *ngFor="let upload of (uploads | async).items;trackBy: trackByFn" [upload]="upload">`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your doubt. But make sure that no action updates the "upload" state while you are rendering the interface. Each time the upload is updated, the ngFor directive will re-render the interface and you will have the feeling that you have lost the changes. I understand that this happens to you because from each one of the list-item you update the state, that modifies the entire list and, consequently, the view is rendered again. In these cases you could give a trackBy function to ngFor to specify how you want the view rendered.